# My `requestLegacyExternalStorage` is not working in Android 11 - API 29

Tags: android, storage, storage-access-framework, android-11

I understand why `requestLegacyExternalStorage` is not working on Android 11 with API 30. However, it doesn't work for me on Android 11 when I am targeting to **API 29**.

Here are the code level differences I observed:

1. Method `StorageManager::getStorageVolumes` was able to list all the volumes on Android 10 (both internal storage and external storage), but it only lists internal storage on Android 11.
2. We also tried `File("/storage").listFiles()`, it returns `null` which means this path doesn't exist.

My app is designed to browse files on external storages, now it stops working on Android 11 as we're not able to see the external storage for some reason.

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" >
    ...
```

Here is my `build.gradle`

```
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion '30.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
...
```

I am wondering if there is anything I missed in order to use the legacy way to access external storages on Android 11.

---

Updated: @blackapps

`File("/storage").listFiles()` returns a `File` object of the external storage with path like `/storage/981B-469E`, and we're allowed to list files in it.

`Context.getExternalFilesDir()` returns a `File` object with path like `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xx.xx/files`

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns a `File` object with path like `/storage/emulated/0`

I am not able to list files inside paths like `/storage/emulated/0`.

Comment: Well, I think the whole point is that you are maybe targeting SDK 29 but it does mean you will get it's permission set. Otherwise one could target SDK lower than intended with unrestricted permission and get them. I think that since you are on Android 11, it's acting as intended. One way around it is using the tree Document that allow you to browse the files and once you select a directory from there you have full access to it

Comment: @DanBaruch Hmm... do you know Google has modified the behaviors of `StorageManager` and it doesn't work for external storages on Android 11 regardless API level? I understand they are pushing developers to scoped storage.

Comment: `but it only lists internal storage on Android 11.` No. Here it lists all volumes. Also usb otg.

Comment: `, it returns null which means this path doesn't exist.` No it exists but you cannot list it.

Comment: `requestLegacyExternalStorage is not working` It will only work on an Android Q/10 device.

Comment: `now it stops working on Android 11 as we're not able to see the external storage for some reason.` Not true. And have a look at getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: @blackapps Hey, are you able to get a `java.io.File` instance for the root folder of the external storage on Android 11? I ask because that what we have by matching subfolders in `File("/storage").listFiles()`.

Comment: @blackapps The `getExternalFilesDirs` only give us access to the app data on the external storage, while we will need access to all files including those created by other apps.

Comment: It gives you the paths to external storage and micro sd card. What you need more? Please tell full paths of both.

Comment: `Hey, are you able to get a java.io.File instance for the root folder of the external storage on Android 11?` Yes of course. Its like always Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().

Comment: @blackapps Hey, I added some more details to the end of my question, I think I am trying to keep the code working same way as Android 10, but I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: `am not able to list files inside paths like /storage/emulated/0.` Mostly there are no files in root of external storage. But you can list directories there on an Android 11 device too. Tell what happens instead.

Comment: Hey @blackapps, we made some progress on this issue in the past few weeks. I think the only issue left is, we don't know the best way to detect if SAF is enabled on the device, we posted another question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67050431/get-usb-storage-volume-android-11. Would you mind to take a look when you get a chance? I really appreciate all your comments and help.

Comment: Her is a possible solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67367047/android-11-primary-directory-invalid-not-allowed-for-content-media-external/67408905#67408905 I encountered same problem and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Android 11 has removed scoped storage so, `legacyExternalStorage` is only seen in Android 10, and ignored in Android 11, if you migrate back to Android 10 then it will work.

or use in `AndroidManifest.xml`

> Manage_External_Storage= true

and ask for Access all file permission from user.

To overcome this situation, Google had given options to use other options, and nothing more is in their documentations.

Comment: I am targeting `Android 12`. Can I remove `legacyExternalStorage`?

Comment: @ThinkAndCode if you remove it, it won't work for Android 10