# Get USB Storage Volume Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, usb, android-11, storage-access-framework

I am working on an app that reads/writes a USB drive using Storage Access Framework. When requesting permission to the USB drive, the app needs to show the permission dialog in the root of the USB drive, so the user can just press one button to grant access instead of navigating to the USB root.

When running the app on a Galaxy S10e running Android 11, I cannot find a way to get the app to display the permission dialog in the USB root. As far as I know there are two ways to do this - either setting the Uri when creating the OPEN_DOCUMEMENT_TREE intent, or calling createOpenDocumentTreeIntent() on a StorageVolume instance. I can see that a USB drive is connected using the UsbDevice class, but no matter what I try, I cannot find the USB drive as a StorageVolume and I cannot get the Uri.

I have tried StorageManager getStorageVolumes() and MediaStore getExternalVolumeNames. I also tried getting a Uri using UsbDrive [getDeviceName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice#getDeviceName()), and creating Uris from "/mnt/sdcard/usb_storage" and "/mnt/sdcard/usbStorage". I have a BroadcastReceiver that listens for android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED, where I can usually get the Uri from the intent data, but this is not being broadcasted. So far I've had zero luck getting this to work.

Does anyone know why this is or if there is a way to make this work?

Comment: `When requesting permission to the USB drive,` ? Not a single idea what you are doing.

Comment: `I cannot find the USB drive as a StorageVolume` On my Android 11 device the USB OTG is in it. But it is not in getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: The app needs the user to grant access to the USB drive using storage access framework. I am using this: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file. I need to set the Uri

Comment: I am also not seeing the USB drive in getExternalFilesDirs(). Do you know why this is?

Comment: As i told you before i do not see that either. Not on 11. Not on 10. And dont post links but tell what you do or post the used code as i still dont know what you mean with: the app needs the user...

Comment: I need a Uri for the usb drive for this function:

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply { if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uri) } }

Comment: But can you use INITIAL_URI for the micro_sd card? Then please post your code. (But not unreadable in a comment).

Comment: I'm following what the documentation says, and they use EXTRA_INITIAL_URI for OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory. If I use EXTRA_OPEN_DOCUMENT it just crashes. Regardless, nothing will work unless I have a Uri for the USB drive.

Comment: The documentation is wrong. EXTRA_INITIAL_URI does not work for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. Please answer my question if you can manage it for a micro sd card.

Comment: `I cannot find the USB drive as a StorageVolume ` And that is the strange thing. If it is not listed you are in problems. Here on 10/11 it is listed so no problem to open it.